# Differentiate angular 5 routes and server side routes

Tags: .net, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, asp.net-routing

I am developing an angular 5 application with .NET core 2.0. I wanted to differentiate the angular 5 routes with hash tag (/#/home) and server side routes from .NET controllers with normal routing (/home). When I apply {usehash:true} in angular, only my angular routes work and server routes don't work. If I remove usehash, its the vice versa. Please help. Thanks.